# Value of toggle button 1 depends on the value of toggle button 2 on a different layout

Tags: android, togglebutton

I have a toggle button on layout 1 and 4 other toggle buttons on layout 2. If the value of at least one of the toggle buttons on the layout 2 is turned on, then the toggle button on the layout 1 must automatically turn on.
Similarly, if I turn off the toggle button in the layout 1, then all the 4 toggle buttons must be turned off.
I've tried this a lot and searched a lot but, was unlucky on all the attempts. Please help.

PS. I am a newbie. Try to explain as detailed as possible.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Create one function that checks the statuses of all buttons, and updates them accordingly. Then call that function from each of the buttons in the `onClickListener()`.

Comment: How do I check the status?

Comment: depends on your implementation, if you want to disable the button, then `button.setEnabled(false)` to disable, and `true` to enable, abd to check if the button is enabled/disabled use `button.isEnabled()`.